# Javascript reload to load a new instance and not reload the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I am using window.location.reload in a jQuery dialog on close. The issue is that if users posted to the page earlier, it will give them a dialog to reload the post data. Is there a way to load the page without "reloading", or "refreshing".

Something similiar to PHP's header("Location");

I need it to load the same url, just not reload it.

I understand that I can use window.location = window.location, but this does not work.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're looking for. But this functionality sounds like a job for Ajax. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `window.location.href = document.URL;`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the direct answers, looking at this issue from a broader scope might help.

The user is being prompted to reload post data because they came to that page via a POST method - if you were to employ the [PRG pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get), you'd avoid the post data prompt, *and* reap the various other benefits it provides. That said, it is a bit more work :)